# What is the right way to say ברכו את ה׳ המברך?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tefillah-betzibbur

What is the right way to say ברכו את ה׳ המברך?

Is it ברכו את (pause) ה׳ המברך as I have heard or ברכו (pause) את ה׳ המברך?

We do find the את having a relationship with ה׳ as in Rabbi Akiva's drosho:

> .. את ה' אלהיך תירא לרבות תלמידי חכמים . .
>
> “Et Hashem Elokecha tira", (the et comes) to include talmidei chachamim" [(Pesachim 22b)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=22b&format=text)

Comment: Maybe their should be a pause before המבורך?

Comment: http://vocaroo.com/i/s1MCjN7VdLuP

Comment: @DoubleAA The way I was taught is that the pause is in order to straighten up for Hashem's name. Thus, either pause to straighten up before es or start to straighten with es and pause to finish straightening after es. Logic would **seem** to mean straighten and then say es Hashem, but I have no proof of this.

Comment: In most shuls I've attended, I've heard the 2nd version - "Barchu" - pause, then the rest. Also, straightening seems to be after "Borchu" (don't know if that's correct, though.) Grammatically, it seems correct to pause between the verb and the object, but, I have no offhand supportive proof of doing that in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The first two words are a verb and the preposition that adjoins it, which wouldn't seem to require a pause. The second and third words are a preposition and the main noun of its object noun phrase, which wouldn't seem to require a pause. The last two words are a noun phrase (a noun and its [predicative nominal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)), which wouldn't seem to require a pause. I wouldn't pause. I have no source beyond this logic.